# How to Change the Text Title of Bottom Modal Sheet dynamically using list in flutter

Tags: android, user-interface, flutter, dart

I have multiple containers arranged in a grid layout in a Flutter Application. When these container widgets are tapped, there is a bottom modal sheet that is triggered. The challenge is that these containers will have to re-use the same bottom modal sheet anytime they are pressed while display the title underneath the container

created a list of titles

```
    List<String> statementTitle = [
      'Accounts',
      'Budget Performance',
      'Cashflow',
      'Income',
      'Financial Position',
      'Tax Assessment'
    ];
class Report extends StatefulWidget {

  int index;

  //Report (this.index);
  Report({Key key, this.index}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ReportState createState() {
    return _ReportState();
  }
}

class _ReportState extends State<Report> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        automaticallyImplyLeading: true,
        iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.black),
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        elevation: 0.0,
        title: Text(
          'Report',
          style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 20,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
              color: Color.fromRGBO(35, 36, 44, 1)),
        ),
      ),
      body: Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 22),
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: <Widget>[

              Container(
                height: 284,
                width: 331,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Color.fromRGBO(242, 243, 255, 1),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(24)),
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    SizedBox(
                      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.027,
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 14.0),
                      child: Text(
                        'Statement',
                        style: new TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 14.0,
                            color: Color.fromRGBO(35, 36, 44, 1),
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                            fontFamily: "Gordita"),
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.022,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Color.fromRGBO(242, 243, 255, 1),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8)),
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          GestureDetector(
                            onTap: () {
                              showModalBottomSheet(
                                  context: context,
                                  builder: (BuildContext bc) {
                                    return _accountModalBottomSheet(context);
                                    ;
                                  });
                            },
                            child: Container(
                              height: 89,
                              width: 90,
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8)),
                              child: Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 14.0),
                                child: Column(
                                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    SizedBox(
                                      height:
                                          MediaQuery.of(context).size.height *
                                              0.016,
                                    ),
                                    Image.asset(
                                      'images/doc.png',
                                      scale: 2,
                                    ),
                                    SizedBox(
                                      height:
                                          MediaQuery.of(context).size.height *
                                              0.015,
                                    ),
                                    Text(
                                      'Accounts',
                                      style: new TextStyle(
                                          fontSize: 10.0,
                                          color: Color.fromRGBO(86, 89, 109, 1),
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                                          fontFamily: "Gordita"),
                                    )
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          GestureDetector(
                            onTap: () {
                              showModalBottomSheet(
                                  context: context,
                                  builder: (BuildContext bc) {
                                    return _accountModalBottomSheet(context);
                                    ;
                                  });
                            },
                            child: Container(
                              height: 89,
                              width: 90,
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8)),
                              child: Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 14.0),
                                child: Column(
                                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    SizedBox(
                                      height:
                                          MediaQuery.of(context).size.height *
                                              0.016,
                                    ),
                                    Image.asset(
                                      'images/doc.png',
                                      scale: 2,
                                    ),
                                    SizedBox(
                                      height:
                                          MediaQuery.of(context).size.height *
                                              0.015,
                                    ),
                                    Text(
                                      'Budget\nPerformance',
                                      style: new TextStyle(
                                          fontSize: 10.0,
                                          color: Color.fromRGBO(86, 89, 109, 1),
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                                          fontFamily: "Gordita"),
                                    )
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),

              ),

  Widget _accountModalBottomSheet(context) {
    return Container(
        color: Color(0xFF737373),
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.6,
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Theme.of(context).canvasColor,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
              topLeft: const Radius.circular(25),
              topRight: const Radius.circular(25),
            ),
          ),
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 22.0),
            child: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                SizedBox(
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.04,
                ),
                Container(
                  child: Text(
                   // '$statementTitle',
                    statementTitle[widget.index],
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                        fontFamily: "Gordita",
                        color: Color.fromRGBO(35, 36, 44, 1),
                        fontSize: 18.0),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.04,
                ),
                Text(
                  'Select a date range',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                      fontFamily: "Gordita",
                      color: Color.fromRGBO(98, 96, 116, 1),
                      fontSize: 14.0),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.04,
                ),
                Container(
                  width: double.infinity,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Color.fromRGBO(249, 249, 249, 1),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8)),
                  child: Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Flexible(
                        child: Stack(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Text(
                              'From',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                                  fontFamily: "Gordita",
                                  color: Color.fromRGBO(98, 96, 116, 1),
                                  fontSize: 12.0),
                            ),
                            TextField(
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                  prefixIcon: Container(
                                height: 16,
                                width: 16,
                                child: Image.asset('images/calendar.png'),
                              )),
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.06,
                      ),
                      Flexible(
                        child: Stack(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Text(
                              'To',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                                  fontFamily: "Gordita",
                                  color: Color.fromRGBO(98, 96, 116, 1),
                                  fontSize: 12.0),
                            ),
                            TextField(
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                  prefixIcon: Container(
                                height: 16,
                                width: 16,
                                child: Image.asset('images/calendar.png'),
                              )),
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.04,
                ),
                Stack(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text('Item'),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 16.0),
                      child: DropdownButton<String>(
                        onChanged: categorySelected,
                        isExpanded: true,
                        value: "Weekly",
                        style: new TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 18.0,
                            color: Color.fromRGBO(35, 36, 44, 1),
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                            fontFamily: "Gordita"),
                        items: <DropdownMenuItem<String>>[
                          const DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                              value: "Weekly", child: const Text("Weekly")),
                          const DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                              value: "Monthly", child: const Text("Monthly")),
                          const DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                              value: "Quarterly",
                              child: const Text("Quarterly")),
                        ],
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.06,
                ),
                Container(
                  height: 48.0,
                  width: double.infinity,
                  decoration:
                      BoxDecoration(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8)),
                  child: RaisedButton(
                    color: Color.fromRGBO(68, 74, 213, 1),
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.of(context).popAndPushNamed('/successReport');
                    },
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        SizedBox(
                          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.9,
                        ),
                        Text(
                          'Fetch Report',
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: Color.fromRGBO(235, 234, 250, 1),
                              fontSize: 14,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                        ),
                        Icon(
                          Icons.arrow_forward,
                          color: Color.fromRGBO(235, 234, 250, 1),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }

  void reportSelected(String value) {}
  void categorySelected(String value) {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can use `for loop` to generate `Widget` you need and pass `statementTitle[i]`
code snippet

```
Row(
 mainAxisAlignment:  MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
 children: <Widget>[
  for (int i = 3; i < statementTitle.length;  i++)
    GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        showModalBottomSheet(
            context: context,
            builder: (BuildContext bc) {
              return _accountModalBottomSheet(
                  context,
                  statementTitle[i]);
            });
      },

...
    Widget _accountModalBottomSheet(context, String statementTitle) {
    return Container(
        color: Color(0xFF737373),
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

List<String> statementTitle = [
  'Accounts',
  'Budget Performance',
  'Cashflow',
  'Income',
  'Financial Position',
  'Tax Assessment'
];

class Report extends StatefulWidget {
  int index;

  //Report (this.index);
  Report({Key key, this.index}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ReportState createState() {
    return _ReportState();
  }
}

class _ReportState extends State<Report> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          automaticallyImplyLeading: true,
          iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.black),
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          elevation: 0.0,
          title: Text(
            'Report',
            style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 20,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                color: Color.fromRGBO(35, 36, 44, 1)),
          ),
        ),
        body: Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 22),
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                      height: 284,
                      width: 400,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Color.fromRGBO(242, 243, 255, 1),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(24)),
                      child: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            SizedBox(
                              height:
                                  MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.027,
                            ),
                            Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 14.0),
                              child: Text(
                                'Statement',
                                style: new TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 14.0,
                                    color: Color.fromRGBO(35, 36, 44, 1),
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                                    fontFamily: "Gordita"),
                              ),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(
                              height:
                                  MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.022,
                            ),
                            Container(
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    color: Color.fromRGBO(242, 243, 255, 1),
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8)),
                                child: Column(
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    Row(
                                        mainAxisAlignment:
                                            MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                                        children: <Widget>[
                                          for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
                                            GestureDetector(
                                              onTap: () {
                                                showModalBottomSheet(
                                                    context: context,
                                                    builder: (BuildContext bc) {
                                                      return _accountModalBottomSheet(
                                                          context,
                                                          statementTitle[i]);
                                                    });
                                              },
                                              child: Container(
                                                height: 89,
                                                width: 90,
                                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                    color: Colors.white,
                                                    borderRadius:
                                                        BorderRadius.circular(
                                                            8)),
                                                child: Padding(
                                                  padding:
                                                      const EdgeInsets.only(
                                                          left: 14.0),
                                                  child: Column(
                                                    crossAxisAlignment:
                                                        CrossAxisAlignment
                                                            .start,
                                                    children: <Widget>[
                                                      SizedBox(
                                                        height: MediaQuery.of(
                                                                    context)
                                                                .size
                                                                .height *
                                                            0.016,
                                                      ),
                                                      Image.asset(
                                                        'images/doc.png',
                                                        scale: 2,
                                                      ),
                                                      SizedBox(
                                                        height: MediaQuery.of(
                                                                    context)
                                                                .size
                                                                .height *
                                                            0.015,
                                                      ),
                                                      Text(
                                                        statementTitle[i],
                                                        style: new TextStyle(
                                                            fontSize: 10.0,
                                                            color:
                                                                Color.fromRGBO(
                                                                    86,
                                                                    89,
                                                                    109,
                                                                    1),
                                                            fontWeight:
                                                                FontWeight
                                                                    .normal,
                                                            fontFamily:
                                                                "Gordita"),
                                                      )
                                                    ],
                                                  ),
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                        ]),
                                    Row(
                                        mainAxisAlignment:
                                            MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                                        children: <Widget>[
                                          for (int i = 3;
                                              i < statementTitle.length;
                                              i++)
                                            GestureDetector(
                                              onTap: () {
                                                showModalBottomSheet(
                                                    context: context,
                                                    builder: (BuildContext bc) {
                                                      return _accountModalBottomSheet(
                                                          context,
                                                          statementTitle[i]);
                                                    });
                                              },
                                              child: Container(
                                                height: 89,
                                                width: 90,
                                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                    color: Colors.white,
                                                    borderRadius:
                                                        BorderRadius.circular(
                                                            8)),
                                                child: Padding(
                                                  padding:
                                                      const EdgeInsets.only(
                                                          left: 14.0),
                                                  child: Column(
                                                    crossAxisAlignment:
                                                        CrossAxisAlignment
                                                            .start,
                                                    children: <Widget>[
                                                      SizedBox(
                                                        height: MediaQuery.of(
                                                                    context)
                                                                .size
                                                                .height *
                                                            0.016,
                                                      ),
                                                      Image.asset(
                                                        'images/doc.png',
                                                        scale: 2,
                                                      ),
                                                      SizedBox(
                                                        height: MediaQuery.of(
                                                                    context)
                                                                .size
                                                                .height *
                                                            0.015,
                                                      ),
                                                      Text(
                                                        statementTitle[i],
                                                        style: new TextStyle(
                                                            fontSize: 10.0,
                                                            color:
                                                                Color.fromRGBO(
                                                                    86,
                                                                    89,
                                                                    109,
                                                                    1),
                                                            fontWeight:
                                                                FontWeight
                                                                    .normal,
                                                            fontFamily:
                                                                "Gordita"),
                                                      )
                                                    ],
                                                  ),
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                        ]),
                                  ],
                                ))
                          ]))
                ]))));
  }

  Widget _accountModalBottomSheet(context, String statementTitle) {
    return Container(
        color: Color(0xFF737373),
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.6,
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Theme.of(context).canvasColor,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
              topLeft: const Radius.circular(25),
              topRight: const Radius.circular(25),
            ),
          ),
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 22.0),
            child: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                SizedBox(
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.04,
                ),
                Container(
                  child: Text(
                    statementTitle,
                    //statementTitle[widget.index],
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                        fontFamily: "Gordita",
                        color: Color.fromRGBO(35, 36, 44, 1),
                        fontSize: 18.0),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.04,
                ),
                Text(
                  'Select a date range',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                      fontFamily: "Gordita",
                      color: Color.fromRGBO(98, 96, 116, 1),
                      fontSize: 14.0),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.04,
                ),
                Container(
                  width: double.infinity,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Color.fromRGBO(249, 249, 249, 1),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8)),
                  child: Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Flexible(
                        child: Stack(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Text(
                              'From',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                                  fontFamily: "Gordita",
                                  color: Color.fromRGBO(98, 96, 116, 1),
                                  fontSize: 12.0),
                            ),
                            TextField(
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                  prefixIcon: Container(
                                height: 16,
                                width: 16,
                                child: Image.asset('images/calendar.png'),
                              )),
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.06,
                      ),
                      Flexible(
                        child: Stack(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Text(
                              'To',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                                  fontFamily: "Gordita",
                                  color: Color.fromRGBO(98, 96, 116, 1),
                                  fontSize: 12.0),
                            ),
                            TextField(
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                  prefixIcon: Container(
                                height: 16,
                                width: 16,
                                child: Image.asset('images/calendar.png'),
                              )),
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.04,
                ),
                Stack(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text('Item'),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 16.0),
                      child: DropdownButton<String>(
                        onChanged: categorySelected,
                        isExpanded: true,
                        value: "Weekly",
                        style: new TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 18.0,
                            color: Color.fromRGBO(35, 36, 44, 1),
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                            fontFamily: "Gordita"),
                        items: <DropdownMenuItem<String>>[
                          const DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                              value: "Weekly", child: const Text("Weekly")),
                          const DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                              value: "Monthly", child: const Text("Monthly")),
                          const DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                              value: "Quarterly",
                              child: const Text("Quarterly")),
                        ],
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.06,
                ),
                Container(
                  height: 48.0,
                  width: double.infinity,
                  decoration:
                      BoxDecoration(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8)),
                  child: RaisedButton(
                    color: Color.fromRGBO(68, 74, 213, 1),
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.of(context).popAndPushNamed('/successReport');
                    },
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        SizedBox(
                          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.9,
                        ),
                        Text(
                          'Fetch Report',
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: Color.fromRGBO(235, 234, 250, 1),
                              fontSize: 14,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                        ),
                        Icon(
                          Icons.arrow_forward,
                          color: Color.fromRGBO(235, 234, 250, 1),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }

  void reportSelected(String value) {}
  void categorySelected(String value) {}
}

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Report(index: 0),
    );
  }
}
```